# EF table-per-hierarchy multiple constructors

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, discriminator, table-per-hierarchy

I have an inherited class configuration that is using TPH and has created a single table with a discriminator column, and some of my own nullable fields

```
public abstract class ActionBase
{
    /// ctor1
    public ActionBase(long issueId)
    {
        IssueId = issueId;
        Url = $"https://mypath.com/{issueId}";
    }

    /// ctor2
    public ActionBase(long issueId, long locationId)
    {
        IssueId = issueId;
        LocationId = locationId;
        Url = $"https://mypath.com/{issueId}/{locationId}";
    }

    public long IssueId {get;set;}
    public long? LocationId {get;set;}
    public Url { get; }
}

public class BlogAction: ActionBase
{        
    /// ctor1
    public ReadBlogAction(long issueId): base(issueId) {}
}

public class LocationAction: ActionBase
{        
    /// ctor1
    public ReadBlogAction(long issueId, long locationId): base(issueId, locationId) {}
}

public class BlogLocationAction: ActionBase
{        
    /// ctor1
    public ReadBlogAction(long issueId): base(issueId) {}

    /// ctor2
    public ReadBlogAction(long issueId, long locationId): base(issueId, locationId) {}
}
```

When I create instances of the `BlogLocationAction` class the first constructor is *always* run. How can I require the 2nd constructor to be used if `LocationId` is not null?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly how you create an instance of the `BlogLocationAction` class.

Comment: A word of caution, as soon as you say null-able columns and inheritance you should stop and really reconsider whether inheritance is the answer. If the Location ID is optional because some subclasses need it and others do not, this is a scenario that is NOT suitable for inheritance. if *all* sub-classes have an optional Location then that is Ok.  Shoving every "similar" record into a single table just because they all seem to share a few common columns is a bad design.

Comment: If I have 10k rows of one thing and 50k rows of another, it is almost always better as separate tables where queries against the first are indexed against 10k rows rather than all queries sifting through 60k rows and probably dealing with missing, useful indexes because common useful columns for one entity end up optional/.null-able because they aren't applicable to the rest.

Comment: The constructors in `BlogLocationAction` can't be from your running code. Please show code that doesn't deviate significantly from what you actually have. And, as already said, show the code that creates `BlogLocationAction`s.

Comment: Apologies @GertArnold I can't, I'm under NDA, I've had to try and demonstrate using a similar alternative :-(